# AWS Cognito not sending verification SMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-cognito

I have setup AWS cognito with my own user pool, but when i create a user with a valid phone number i did not receive verification SMS on that phone.
I have also created role to allow Amazon Cognito to send SMS messages.
Please help me to debug the issue and let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: You attached role to access Amazon SNS to send messages to phone number. Have you increased spend limit in Amazon SNS?

Comment: @KumareshBabu how to increase SNS limit?

Comment: You can open AWS Support center and create case. Under regarding, choose Service Limit Increase. For SNS, follow the link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_sns

Comment: @KumareshBabu raised SNS limit from 1 to 50 but not receiving any SMS yet.

Comment: @KumareshBabu thanks for the help, issue resolved post your comments as answer, i will accept it.

Comment: After raising SNS limit, is it sending SMS ?

Comment: @KumareshBabu yes after raising SNS limit.

Comment: Was there any sign that it was a limit issue?

Comment: Not receiving SMS after the limit increase. Anything else can help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can open AWS Support center and create case. Under regarding, choose Service Limit Increase. For SNS, follow the link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_sns