# AWS Cognito not sending verification SMS to Google Fi phone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I perform an update on the user to update his phone using boto3 as follows:

```
response = cognito_client.admin_update_user_attributes(
                UserPoolId=os.environ['cognito_user_pool_id'],
                Username=username,
                UserAttributes=att_list
        )
```

When I use a number that does not use Google Fi it **works fine**.
When I use a number that uses Google Fi, the message is **not delivered**.

I have followed the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521029/aws-cognito-not-sending-verification-sms) and increased the quota to $50, but there was no change.

Cognito does have the necessary permissions to use SNS and the quota should be more than enough now. Cognito does not through any error in either case.

**Has anyone experienced a similar behavior and would know how to resolve it?**